# Jquery update 1-3 code issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a older script that I use to use. I am not a jquery type person and I am having difficulties getting a script to work.

I am using jquery 3.2.1 but I can only get this to work using jquery 1.11.1
I am not sure what I am looking for or what is causing the issue.

the script is located here http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/07/username-live-availability-check-using.html

**This issue code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#username").change(function(){

var username = $("#username").val();
var msgbox = $("#status");

if(username.length > 4){

$("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> Checking availability...');

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax.php",  
    data: "username="+ username,  
    success: function(msg){  
   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
    if(msg == 'OK')    {

        $("#username").removeClass("red");
        $("#username").addClass("green");
        msgbox.html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle">');

    } else  {

         $("#username").removeClass("green");
         $("#username").addClass("red");
        msgbox.html(msg);
    }  

   });
   }

 });

} else {
$("#username").addClass("red");
$("#status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Please enter atleast 5 letters</font>');
}
return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following is works with version 3

```
$(function() {    

$("#username").keyup(function(){

var username = $("#username").val();
var msgbox = $("#status");

if(username.length > 3){

$("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax.php",  
    data: "username="+ username,  
    success: function(msg){  

    if(msg == 'OK') { 

        $("#username").removeClass("red");
        $("#username").addClass("green");
        msgbox.html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle">');

    } else  { 

         $("#username").removeClass("green");
         $("#username").addClass("red");
        msgbox.html(msg);
    }  

   } 

 }); 

} else {

$("#username").addClass("red");
$("#status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Please enter atleast 5 letters</font>');
}
return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoy are using `ajaxComplete` inside success callback function, that doesn't make sense, since success callback will fire when ajax finishes. Also, according to [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) :

> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events,
>   **including those added with the .ajaxComplete() method**, must be
>   attached to document.

Try to remove the line:

```
$("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
```

and its closing bracket and parenthesis:

```
});
```

Also, `$(document).ready(function(){` is deprecated in jQuery 3. Replace it with `$(function() {`

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and when I do it stops functioning all together

Comment: You have picked a correct answer which is what I told you, except that you needed to change `$("#username").change(function(){` to `$("#username").keyup(function(){`. If you want to also handle copy/paste in your field, you can change it to `$("#username").on("input", function() {`.